# What happens if I do integration in a non inertial reference frame?

Tags: reference-frames, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

I am creating a 6dof rigid body simulation for aircraft flying through the atmosphere, and when defining my global coordinate system I am deciding between using the [ECEF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF) coordinate system (clamped to the ground and rotates with the earth) and the [ECI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_Centered_Inertial) coordinate system (does not rotate with the earth) for integration of forces and moments.

How can I estimate the error that I would accumulate by using ECEF vs ECI?

Comment: A  lot depends on how error-prone you are to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most aircraft simulations, you don't need to worry about the differences.  They're far smaller than other forces acting on the aircraft.

If you do want to look at what those errors are, you can use the rotating-frame equations of motion.  These are the same as the inertial frame equations of motion but they have additional terms for the centripetal and Coreolis effects.  If you're using the rotating-frame equations of motion in a rotating frame, the results are as correct as if you used inertial-frame equations of motion in an inertial frame.  If you do that you won't have any errors due to your frame choice.

For a practical data point, the Coreolis effect on a sniper bullet fired 1 mile is on the order of an inch.  Not knowing your target level of fidelity, I can't say if that matters to you or not, but there's *many* aerodynamic effects that are hard to model and play a greater part than frame errors, so as a very qualitative statement, you can safely ignore them until you have a rather advanced model.